# How to wrap the word int the preview of pagedown editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html code

```
    <div style="padding-top:20px;" class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
                    <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input"></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:20px;" class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

My javascript code:

```
(function () {
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

    converter1.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
        return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
        });
    });

    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);

    editor1.run();

})();
```

My CSS code for vmd-preview:

```
.wmd-preview 
{
    border:2px solid #979797;
}

.wmd-preview 
{
    background-color:#E0EAF1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #b3cee1;
    border-right:1px solid #b3cee1;
    padding:3px 4px 3px 4px;
    margin:2px 2px 2px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:90%;
    line-height:2.4;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.wmd-preview
{
    clear:both;
    padding:3px;
    border:2px dotted #ccc;
    font-size:107%;
    line-height:130%;
    width:660px;
}

.wmd-preview p
{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.wmd-preview li
{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.wmd-preview li pre
{
    word-wrap:normal;
}

.wmd-preview img
{   
    max-width:640px;
}
```

Why I keep writing int the editor without change line, the preview will extends its width and cannot auto wrap, What's wrong in my code?

PS: my browser is google chrome

Comment: It would help more if you create a fiddle for the problem.

Comment: You could try removing white-space:nowrap; from your first .wmd-preview class. [demo](http://jsbin.com/AjiBeti/1/) Note: it is also good practice not to use the same name for id and class, and style this way: #id, .class

Comment: @D.Alexander thank you so much, it works now! You mean in the html code, I should not use the same name for class and id?

Comment: @Charles Great to hear that it works! If my answer below helps, and solves the problem, please check the 'accept answer' checkmark icon. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from the comments above, the issue here is that the inner text is being set to never break. By just removing `white-space:nowrap;` from that element, the initial problem is solved.

View this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AjiBeti/2/).

Regarding naming and styling IDs and classes, it is generally best practice to avoid using the same exact string for both - even though it might render successfully. This is due to possible naming conflicts you may run into in your code later on, but also so it is more readable for you and others who might need to edit your code someday.

In the example demo above, I used [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (or lowerCamelCase) for IDs and hyphenated class names. You can choose any style that works for you, and there are many. Check out [some other naming conventions](https://www.google.com/#q=css%20id%20class%20naming%20convention) out there and give one a try. You'll really be glad you did!